# Magnetocaloric effect

Tags: thermodynamics

Does a MCM (magnetocaloric material) reject same heat from a different starting temperature,when entering inside a field with the same intensity?

I mean: If I start with a MCM at 10°C and i enter inside 1T field and it rejects 10J of heat,does the same mass of MCM at 15° entering inside a 1T field rejects 10J of heat too?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

http://electrons.wikidot.com/magnetocaloric-effiect 
I think it should reject less heat in the second case,see the graph for entropy

Answer (score 0):

No it wouldn't, except if your cristal has a very large T$_c$. In short, magnetocaloric effect (EMC) and rotative magnetocaloric effect (EMCR) expected maximum heat transfer occurs nearby a magnetic transition.

The reason for this is that it is at this point that magnetization changes the most, and therefore entropy as well, which leads to the greatest change in temperature which leads to the highest heat transfer.

Hope it helps, cheers.